# jquery conditional logic problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a drop down menu that only disappears, when both drop down menus itself and hovered list item aren't hovered over.

This what I'm already using makes the submenu appears, only when li item is hovered over, but it disappears when the submenu is hovered and I have to fix that.

Javascript:

```
<script>        
$(document).ready(function () {     
$("#menu-top li:nth-child(1)").hover(   
function () {      $('#dropdown_first').slideDown('fast');   },    
function () {      $('#dropdown_first').slideUp('fast');   } );  });                
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu-top"> 
<li>first item</li>
<li>second item</li>
<li>third item</li>
</div>
```

..further down page:

```
<div id="dropdown_first">
first menu dropdown
</div> 

<style>#dropdown_first {display:none'}
```

I think I need an `if` statement here to say only to use callback slideup, when mouseout is true for both submenus and li item, but am stuck. Can anybody help me?

Comment: It's easier to use css to achieve dropdown menu effect.

Comment: Sorry, but I just can't parse "I needn't drop down menu to only disappear when both drop down menu itself and hovered list item aren't hovered over." Could you perhaps rephrase how you want it to behave?

Comment: I'm trying to make the drop down menu only disappear when both the hovered list item and the dropdown menu itself are not hovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to use JS for the effect ,give the below a try. 
I have written it off hand so have not been able to test it but it should resolve the problem you are having (hopefully).

At top:

```
<style>
#dropdown_first {
display:none;
}
</style>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>        
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#menu-top li:nth-child(1)").hover(function(){
$('#dropdown_first').slideDown('fast');
});

$("#menu-top").mouseleave(function(){
$('#dropdown_first').slideUp('fast');
});

});         
</script>
```

Hope that helps